# Running another JRE aside from the default version

Tags: java

How can I run a java version (1.6.0_20) when the default java version installed in my machine is Java 1.6.0_30?

Comment: I think you need to point your JAVA_HOME to 1.6.0_20

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your `PATH` environment variable:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/java/1.6.0_20       # Unsure if this definitely necessary.
$ export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

From the command line, explicitly use the version of the Java executable that you want.

```
C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\java <Main>
```

With Eclipse IDE, you can set the JDK to use in the project settings.

With a general system setup, change the `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` variables to point to the desired version.